# Magento product "Save Button" not working

Tags: magento2, product

I am running **Magento 2.2.2** and suddenly the products cant be saved anymore. Clicking the save button has no effect at all. There are no errors in the console. The network tab in Chromes dev tools shows no traffic when the button is clicked. I redeployed, cleared cache, nothing helped.

Any ideas where to start looking?

Comment: do `var/log/system.log` or `var/log/exceptions.log` give any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a good chance validation is failing. You just cant see it to correct it. There are a lot of hidden fields within the admin. Open inventory or pricing on the problem product to see if anything is highlighted in red.

Comment: That was it :-)!

Comment: I got caught out by exact same thing. 1 hour wasted scratching my head.